# Add advertisement to a page

Tags: codeigniter, ads

I am working on a project made in Codeigniter and want to add some advertisements in it. I am currently running the project in my local machine. Does anyone have any idea where can I get the advertisement scripts for free?

All positive responses are appreciated.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: choose one ad(re)seller and then adhere to its doc.

Comment: @mnagel They are all paid. I need something, that can provide me free ads script to include it in my project. Do you know any such website?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are running on local pc, then you don't need online ads like Google Adsense. It's better just add a static banner for now. Static banners are more likely image files. You can have some via: [Google Search Ubuntu Banner](https://www.google.com/search?q=ubuntu%20banner%20image&oq=ubuntu%20banner%20image&aqs=chrome.0.69i57j69i62.7906j0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#sclient=psy-ab&q=ubuntu%20banner%20image&oq=ubuntu%20banner%20image&gs_l=serp.12...0.0.0.2111.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0..0.0...0.0.0..1c..17.psy-ab.vN9B_I_2lWc&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_qf.&bvm=bv.48705608,d.Yms&fp=376b7a2f9b9f161f&biw=1366&bih=643)

Comment: But, what if I want to add real adds? Is there any way, by which I can do that?

Comment: You can add real "dynamic" ads through advertiser companies like Google Adsense. To know more about Google Adsense, you can google "Adsense" or "publish ads on your web site" keyphrases for more results.